# Optionally skip serializing a field with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I have two structs:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Post {
    title: String,
    // ...more fields...,
    comments: Vec<Comment>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Comment {
    body: String,
    // ...more fields...,
}
```

I want to generate 2 kinds of JSON files:

1. A JSON index of a `Vec<Post>` which should include all fields except `comments`.
2. A JSON of a `Post` which includes all fields.

Is it possible to achieve this with the `Serialize` derive attribute? I found [`skip_serializing_if`](https://serde.rs/attr-skip-serializing.html) attribute in Serde's documentation but as far as I can see, it's not useful for me because I want to skip not based on the value of the field but based on which JSON file I'm generating.

Right now I'm generating the index using the `json!` macro which requires manually listing all the fields of `Post` but I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to generate 2 kinds of JSON files

I read that as "2 **types** of JSON files", so I turn towards that as a solution. I'd create wrapper types custom-fit to each context. These can take references to the original type to avoid too much memory overhead:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct LightweightPost<'a> {
    title: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a Post> for LightweightPost<'a> {
    fn from(other: &'a Post) -> Self {
        LightweightPost {
            title: &other.title,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let posts = vec![
        Post {
            title: "title".into(),
            comments: vec![Comment { body: "comment".into() }],
        },
    ];

    let listing: Vec<_> = posts.iter().map(LightweightPost::from).collect();

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&listing).unwrap());
    // [{"title":"title"}]

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&posts[0]).unwrap());
    // {"title":"title","comments":[{"body":"comment"}]}
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2cf2c500953fb06599644219d588eee1&version=stable)

---

Editorially, I've found this type of multiple-type structure very useful when writing web apps in Ruby, using the [roar gem](https://github.com/trailblazer/roar). These new types allow for places to hang behavior  specific to certain contexts such as validation or persistence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I might stick with `json!` for now as that's shorter than creating a new struct and then implementing a conversion function.